# Function of "plus" button in the Neo4j web interface

Tags: user-interface, neo4j, user-controls

In the Neo4j web interface, what is the function of the button with "+" on it?

[image]

Comment: It was originally intended to spawn a new editor-frame but then was degenerated to just reset the input area. We will rework it going forward. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does basically just clear the query buffer, but the main way I use it is to distinguish editing a saved query from typing a new one. If you type a query you can save it by clicking the "star" button. That button is now highlighted, indicating that you are viewing a saved query. If you change the query, the star button (still highlighted) will turn into an exclamation mark, indicating that if you click it now you will save the changes you've made to the query. This is true also when deleting all the characters in the buffer. If you start typing again, the exclamation mark returns, indicating that you are still editing the same saved query. If you want create a new query, that has nothing to do with the saved query, the plus button let's you do that.

I use this mainly when I store several similar versions of a query: create the first version, save it, copy query, click plus, paste, edit, save second version, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

It just cleans up the input line. Instead you could just mark everything (`Ctrl+A`) and remove (`Ctrl+X`).

Comment: but then esp. with  a saved query, you are still in the context of the saved query.